# Dynamic parameters in ember route doesn't render view

Tags: ember.js

I have a requirement to use query parameters in ember. So, I am using dynamic routing.

My Route looks like

```
MyApp.Application.MyModuleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({    
   model: function (params) {
     return jQuery.getJSON("/myModule/" + params.uid);
   }
});
```

And my mapper looks like

```
MyApp.Application.Router.map(function () {
   this.resource('myModule', { path: '/myModule/:uid/:version' });
});
```

When I browse for myMachine/#/myModule, view gets rendered.

When I browse for myMachine/#/myModule/123/1 it doesn't render the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a trick to solve this issue.

I used another route to redirect to the original route so that the view is rendered.

```
MyApp.Application.MyModule1Route = Ember.Route.extend({     
  model: function (params) {
    //take the parameters
    //Redirect to MyModule2Route 
    }
  }
});

MyApp.Application.MyModule2Route = Ember.Route.extend({    
  model: function (params) {
    //Redirect to MyModule1Route 
  }
});
```